# How do I query Drupal 8 Media by type?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-preprocess

I've created a Media type called "ad_gallery" can I can't seem to pull in all the entries while preprocessing.

I'm trying

```
\Drupal::entityQuery('media')->condition('type','ad_gallery')->execute();
```

And it's saying:

> Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException: 'type' not found in Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Tables->ensureEntityTable()

Is there a different way to query these than there is nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `bundle` instead of `type`.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
\Drupal::entityQuery('media')->condition('bundle', 'ad_gallery')->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.